# Does Liouville's theorem hold if the function is bounded from below?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given f an entire function, assume there exists an m>0 s.t. |f(z)|$\geq$ m $\forall$ z $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$. Show that f is constant. It seems awfully a lot like liouville's theorem but I am not sure on the bound.

Comment: Note that you need $m > 0$.

Comment: Apologies missed it out by accident.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\frac{1}{f}$.

[30 characters minimum]

Answer (score 0):

As in the proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra using Liouville's theorem, where you assume the polynomial is never zero, then get it bounded away from zero, then invert it...  consider the reciprocal of $f$ (if $m\gt0$).